# Finding a Product of Matrices to Match a Given Target Matrix $\Bbb R^d$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem in linear algebra and would appreciate some insights.

Given a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I have a target matrix defined as $(I - \frac{1}{2} vv^T)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $vv^T$ is the outer product of $v$ with itself.

My question is whether it is possible to find an integer $k$ and a set of vectors $\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_k\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the product of matrices defined by
$\Pi_{i=1}^{k} (I + z_i z_i^T)$ is equal to the target matrix $(I - \frac{1}{2} vv^T)$.

If such a representation is possible, how can one determine the minimal value of $k$ and find the specific vectors $z_i$? Additionally, does the feasibility of this representation or the values of $k$ and $z_i$ depend on the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Thank you in advance for your insights and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For any real vector $z_i$, $I + z_i z_i^T$ has determinant $\ge 1$ ($> 1$ if $z_i \ne 0$) and so the product of $k$ of them has determinant $\ge 1$.  On the other hand, $I - v v^T/2$ has determinant $\le 1$ ($< 1$ if $v \ne 0$).  So they can't be equal except in the trivial case $v = 0$, all $z_i = 0$.